# Getting null when trying to populate nested ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a models like this:

```
   public class VMDetallePeriodoPAgo
    {
        public DetallePeriodoPagoViewModel Modelo1 { get; set; }
        public PerspectivaRealViewModel Modelo2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class DetallePeriodoPagoViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int IdRecibo { get; set; }

        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        public int IdPeriodoPago { get; set; }

        public string Empleado { get; set; }

        public decimal Ingresos { get; set; }

        public decimal MontoISR { get; set; }
    }

    public class PerspectivaRealViewModel
    {
        public decimal PersepcionesReales { get; set; }
    }
```

And in controller I want to fill it as:

```
List<VMDetallePeriodoPAgo> LDPVM = new List<VMDetallePeriodoPAgo>();
            foreach (var i in periodos)
            {
                VMDetallePeriodoPAgo DPVM = new VMDetallePeriodoPAgo();

                DPVM.Modelo1.IdRecibo = i.IdRecibo;
                DPVM.Modelo1.Empleado = i.Empleado.Codigo;
                DPVM.Modelo1.Descripcion = i.Descripcion;
                DPVM.Modelo1.MontoISR = i.MontoIRS;
                LDPVM.Add(DPVM);
            }
```

Problem is when I try to execute it, when trying to fill model in line:

```
 DPVM.Modelo1.IdRecibo = i.IdRecibo;
```

I always getting:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Why it happen, am I doing something wrong with my modeling? Regards

Comment: In VMDetallePeriodoPAgo constructor make sure you create a new instance as

public VMDetallePeriodoPAgo()
{
 Modelo1 = new DetallePeriodoPagoViewModel(); 
}

if not withing foreach make sure you create a new instance before assignment like

DPVM.Modelo1 = new DetallePeriodoPagoViewModel(); 
 DPVM.Modelo1.IdRecibo = i.IdRecibo;
                DPVM.Modelo1.Empleado = i.Empleado.Codigo;
                DPVM.Modelo1.Descripcion = i.Descripcion;
                DPVM.Modelo1.MontoISR = i.MontoIRS;
                LDPVM.Add(DPVM);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize the child object before you can use it:

Update the code in `DPVM` object initialization as

```
VMDetallePeriodoPAgo DPVM = new VMDetallePeriodoPAgo() {Modelo1 = new DetallePeriodoPagoViewModel() , Modelo2 = new PerspectivaRealViewModel() };
```

When an object is instantiated, it is allocated with a block of memory and configured as per the blueprint provided by the class underlying the object.

Answer (score 1):

Add this above your code:

```
DPVM.Modelo1 = new DetallePeriodoPagoViewModel(); //Added code.
DPVM.Modelo1.IdRecibo = i.IdRecibo;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is not related to nesting or ViewModel. 
Modelo1 and Modelo2 was not initialized in code you provided.

You can try the following:

```
public class VMDetallePeriodoPAgo
{
    public DetallePeriodoPagoViewModel Modelo1 { get; set; }
    public PerspectivaRealViewModel Modelo2 { get; set; }

    public VMDetallePeriodoPAgo()
    {
            Modelo1 = new DetallePeriodoPagoViewModel();
            Modelo2 = new PerspectivaRealViewModel();
    }
}
```